# Mac Safari html5 video not working

Tags: macos, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm using video-js player for .webm, .mp4 videos, in all players is working fine but not on Mac Safari 6 (didn't test other versions).
I have MIME type in my .htaccess file for webm and mp4.
Does anyone have some experience with this?
Thanks

Note: Videos are working well on my local server, just online is problem.

Comment: Can you provide a URL at which we can see the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's protected by password of my company.